# Comparing array to scalar

Tags: arrays, r, scalar

**Problem:**

I want to **compare a 2-dimensional array and a scalar** variable, both with numerical values with (<=) lessthanorequalto operation and assign all those values in the array to a vector.

I want to **speed up this task in R**.

Now, below is the code I am using (which is obviously quite time consuming)

**Code I am using now :**

2d_examplearray; # My 2-dimensional array actual size 3500 X 4200 
   my_scalarvariable=5; # some arbitrary value as this is an example

dims_2darray=dim(2d_examplearray); # Get no. of rows & columns information

```
# First create and then initialize vectors for storing values accordingly as specified in if # condition below

eachelementin_ltvector<-vector();
eachelementin_gtvector<-vector();

eachelementin_ltvector=1;
eachelementin_gtvector=1;

for (eachrow in 1 : dims_2darray[1])
{
for (eachcol in 1 : dims_2darray[2])
{
if(2d_examplearray[eachrow,eachcol]<my_scalarvariable)
{
vector_lessthanvalue[eachelementin_ltvector]=2d_examplearray[eachrow,eachcol];
eachelementin_ltvector=eachelementin_ltvector+1;
}
else # greater than or equal to my scalar variable then
{
vector_greaterthanvalue[eachelementin_gtvector]=2d_examplearray[eachrow,eachcol];
eachelementin_gtvector=eachelementin_gtvector+1;
}
}
}
```

Thanks for the inputs on my previous post regarding the same question.
I am new to R and this Q&A forum.

Thanks again

Comment: Please show a small example and expected output based on that.  For guidelines, check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Did you try to google `R subsetting`?

Comment: `indx <- yourmatrix<= scalarvariable; yourmatrix[indx] <- vector1` But, the lengths of vector1 should be the same as the length of `yourmatrix`.  Without a reproducible example, it is not easy to code

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), but your solution will probably be of the form

```
m= 3 # 3500
n= 4 # 4200
set.seed(123)
m <- matrix(rnorm(m*n), m, n)
m
#            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]
# [1,] -0.5604756 0.07050839  0.4609162 -0.4456620
# [2,] -0.2301775 0.12928774 -1.2650612  1.2240818
# [3,]  1.5587083 1.71506499 -0.6868529  0.3598138

v = 1.5 # the value you want elements less than or equal to

m <= v
#       [,1]  [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]  TRUE  TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [2,]  TRUE  TRUE TRUE TRUE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

But you need to specify how you want the matrix to be mapped from two to one dimensions.

For example, you could do

```
unlist(m[m <= v])
```

Which as you can see goes top to bottom, left to right.

```
#    [1] -0.56047565 -0.23017749  0.07050839  0.12928774  0.46091621 -1.26506123 -0.68685285 -0.44566197  1.22408180  0.35981383
```

Comment: I started out making this a comment, but I needed a code block.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I can't say if that's exactly what you are looking for, but I created an example that might be helpful:

```
mat <- matrix(1:14700000, 3500, 4200)

vector <- c(-1:-1000000)
scalar <- 1000000
mat[mat <= scalar]  <- c(-1:-1000000)
```

Note that `vector` must be the same length of the elements being replaced.

Comment: Thank you all for your time and inputs. I am new to R programming and this forum.

Answer (score 0):

'which' might be useful:

```
> A <- matrix( sample(3500*4200)/(3500*4200),3500,4200 )

> b <- 0.3

> v <- A[which(A<=b)]

> system.time( for (n in 1:100) { A[which(A<=b)] } )
       User      System verstrichen 
      30.61        6.05       37.78 

> summary(v)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
7.00e-08 7.50e-02 1.50e-01 1.50e-01 2.25e-01 3.00e-01 

> w <- unlist(A[A<=b])

> system.time( for ( n in 1:100) { unlist(A[A<=b]) } )
       User      System verstrichen 
      32.51        7.22       40.14 

> summary(w)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
7.00e-08 7.50e-02 1.50e-01 1.50e-01 2.25e-01 3.00e-01 

> identical (v,w)
[1] TRUE
```